# maven profile activated but do not execute spring profile work

Tags: maven, profile, spring-boot-maven-plugin

in a maven multi modules project,
i have a configuration like this below..

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>debug</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>debug</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>-Dapp.basedir=${project.build.directory} -Xmx256M
                            -XX:+UseG1GC -Xdebug
                            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8003</jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

when i launch application with the command line :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=debug
```

the terminal linux stack says :

```
c.a.epr.core.SpringApplication          : The following profiles are active: debug
```

but the behaviour of the application is like a NO PROFILE behaviour.
What gets wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should use

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdebug
```

Comment: it was the good way !

Comment: but i'd like to understand why official documentation does not mention this -P<profile> command ! https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/pdf/spring-boot-maven-plugin-reference.pdf. Official documentation mention mvn spring-boot:run -Dapp.profiles=<profile> and mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=<profile> which never work !!!!

Comment: because you put it into profile, so it won't activate if you didn't set -Pdebug
but in official document just use app.profiles as a varialbe, so. you can change easily with -Dapp.profiles=test